ADO Connection for Excel on Sharepoint
I built an excel file with macro code that accesses a lot of data on one of its own worksheets. I use an ADO connection so that I can use SQL on the data. This worked fine on my local computer. When I moved the file to our network drive I get errors at the line of code that executes the connection. My connection string is made from ThisWorkbook.FullName and now that the file is on a sharepoint drive that looks like a url.
https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/directoryPath/file.xlsm

I am thinking that either this url is the problem or else it has something to do with network credentials. If there is a way to skip this and just tell excel 'hey you are only accessing another worksheet in the same file you already have open' that would be easier... But I don't know how to do that. Here is my code (Thank you!):
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName

strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
  & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
cn.Open strCon


The file has to be saved on disk to open the ADO connection, and that only works via a non-HTTP path, so you'd need to save a temporary local copy and query that (you could copy the worksheet to a new file and save that to your Temp directory).

I had read somewhere that http was not allowed in connection strings but this web site seems to disagree:
https://www.connectionstrings.com/sharepoint/

Those connection strings/providers are for querying SharePoint data such as lists etc, (ie. not for querying Excel files stored on SP)

But check out: https://ssbipolar.com/2018/10/29/power-query-connecting-to-excel-workbooks-in-sharepoint-online/

Thank you Tim. An interesting read. I am not sure that Power Query allows one to automate data handling, formatting and presentation the way VBA does but it could be a nice platform to test SQL in.

Here's an example of creating a local copy of the sheet(s) to be queried via ADO (assumes the queried data is static)
First query against a sheet will be relatively slow but subsequent ones will be much faster.
Sub Tester()
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .UsedRange.Clear
        
        Set rs = RunSQL("select * from [Sheet2$]", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2"))
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
        
        Set rs = RunSQL("select * from [Sheet3$]", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3"))
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J2").CopyFromRecordset rs
        
    End With
    
End Sub

'Run some sql against a worksheet (using locally-saved copy)
Function RunSQL(sql As String, ws As Worksheet) As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection 'cache once created
    Set cn = LocalSheetConnection(ws)
    Set RunSQL = cn.Execute(sql)
End Function

Function LocalSheetConnection(ws As Worksheet) As ADODB.Connection
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, wb As Workbook, TempPath As String
    Static PathDict As Object 'cache local path
    If PathDict Is Nothing Then Set PathDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    If Not PathDict.Exists(ws.Name) Then 'create local copy if not already created
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ws.Copy                  'copy to new workbook and save
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        TempPath = GetTempPath()
        wb.SaveAs TempPath, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        wb.Close False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        PathDict.Add ws.Name, TempPath 'cache path with sheet name as key
    End If
    Set LocalSheetConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    LocalSheetConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
                PathDict(ws.Name) & _
                ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
End Function

Function GetTempPath() As String
    With CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
        '2=TempFolder
        GetTempPath = .GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\" & .GetTempName() & ".xlsx"
    End With
End Function


I appreciate you taking the time to answer. But if you read my original post it said I had it working fine on a local copy. I was trying to see if the ADO connection string would work over a URL to a sharepoint location. So I think your original comment is the answer to my question, which is "No, URLs are not allowed."  I don't know how to mark that comment as the accepted answer...

I'm only suggesting a workaround which might allow you to continue using the file in the same way as previously, even if it's stored on SharePoint/OneDrive.

I know I'm getting outside the scope of the original posted question, but would you know if Sharepoint URLs would be allowed in a connection string to an Access database? Or is there an easy way to connect to an Access database on Sharepoint? I could store data on the network that way.

You can export Access data to sharepoint list(s) - see for example: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-link-or-move-data-to-sharepoint-65bf7b03-74bf-445c-959a-24b7a401ddee#:~:text=Use%20the%20Export%20Tables%20to%20SharePoint%20Wizard   You can use ADO to query Sharepoint lists - for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76182332/vba-sql-updating-sharepoint-lists-any-way-to-use-a-single-ado-connection-to-con
